# Accelerated C++ Exercise 4-0

Tags: c++, makefile

I am working through Accelerated C++ by Andrew Koenig and Barbara Moo (2000) and am stuck on code from Chapter 4. I think this code reads an external data file containing exam, final and homework grades for multiple students and returns a course grade for each student.

I have downloaded solutions for the exercises from Andrew Koenig from GitHub:

https://github.com/bitsai/book-exercises/tree/master/Accelerated%20C%2B%2B

I can run the first example in Chapter 4 (`main1.cc`) which returns a course grade for a single student when the midterm, final and homework grades are entered from the keyboard. Here is an example:

```
data: harriet 85 95 88 87 93 45 76 99
student name = harriet
midterm grade = 85
final grade = 95
median of six homework grades (88, 87, 93, 45, 76, 99) = 87.5
final grade = 90
0.2 * 85 + 0.4 * 95 + 0.4 * 87.5 = 90
```

But I cannot run the second example (`main2.cc`) in which data are read for multiple students from an external file. No error messages appear when I create or run the `main2.exe` file. The cursor in the Windows 10 command window simply moves to the next line when I try to run `main2.exe` and nothing is displayed, not even the directory. Here are the lines returned when I make the executables:

```
c:\Users\mark_\myCppprograms\mychapter04>make
g++     main1.cc   -o main1
g++     main2.cc   -o main2
g++    -c -o main3.o main3.cc
g++    -c -o grade.o grade.cc
g++    -c -o median.o median.cc
g++    -c -o Student_info.o Student_info.cc
g++   main3.o grade.o median.o Student_info.o   -o main3
```

The code in `main2.cc` is long. The third example in Chapter 4 (`main3.cc`) breaks this code into multiple `C++` and `header` files but I cannot get the `main3.exe` file to return anything either.

Here is the code for `main2.cc`. I changed `#include "../minmax.h"` to `#include "minmax.h"` and put a file `"minmax.h"` in the same folder as `main2.cc`. The file `"minmax.h"` did not come from the aforementioned GitHub site and I paste its contents below.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
//#include "../minmax.h"
#include "minmax.h"
#else
using std::max;
#endif

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::domain_error;
using std::endl;
using std::istream;
using std::ostream;
using std::setprecision;
using std::setw;
using std::sort;
using std::streamsize;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

struct Student_info {
  string name;
  double midterm, final;
  vector<double> homework;
};  // note the semicolon--it's required

// compute the median of a `vector<double>'
// note that calling this function copies the entire argument `vector'
double median(vector<double> vec) {
#ifdef _MSC_VER
  typedef std::vector<double>::size_type vec_sz;
#else
  typedef vector<double>::size_type vec_sz;
#endif

  vec_sz size = vec.size();
  if (size == 0)
    throw domain_error("median of an empty vector");

  sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

  vec_sz mid = size/2;

  return size % 2 == 0 ? (vec[mid] + vec[mid-1]) / 2 : vec[mid];
}

// compute a student's overall grade from midterm and final exam grades and homework grade
double grade(double midterm, double final, double homework) {
  return 0.2 * midterm + 0.4 * final + 0.4 * homework;
}

// compute a student's overall grade from midterm and final exam grades
// and vector of homework grades.
// this function does not copy its argument, because `median' does so for us.
double grade(double midterm, double final, const vector<double>& hw) {
  if (hw.size() == 0)
    throw domain_error("student has done no homework");

  return grade(midterm, final, median(hw));
}

double grade(const Student_info& s) {
  return grade(s.midterm, s.final, s.homework);
}

// read homework grades from an input stream into a `vector<double>'
istream& read_hw(istream& in, vector<double>& hw) {
  if (in) {
    // get rid of previous contents
    hw.clear();

    // read homework grades
    double x;
    while (in >> x)
      hw.push_back(x);

    // clear the stream so that input will work for the next student
    in.clear();
  }

  return in;
}

istream& read(istream& is, Student_info& s) {
  // read and store the student's name and midterm and final exam grades
  is >> s.name >> s.midterm >> s.final;

  read_hw(is, s.homework);  // read and store all the student's homework grades

  return is;
}

bool compare(const Student_info& x, const Student_info& y) {
  return x.name < y.name;
}

int main() {
  vector<Student_info> students;
  Student_info record;
  string::size_type maxlen = 0;

  // read and store all the records, and find the length of the longest name
  while (read(cin, record)) {
    maxlen = max(maxlen, record.name.size());
    students.push_back(record);
  }

  // alphabetize the records
  sort(students.begin(), students.end(), compare);
  
#ifdef _MSC_VER
  for (std::vector<Student_info>::size_type i = 0;
#else
       for (vector<Student_info>::size_type i = 0;
#endif
        i != students.size(); ++i) {

     // write the name, padded on the right to `maxlen' `+' `1' characters
     cout << students[i].name
          << string(maxlen + 1 - students[i].name.size(), ' ');

     // compute and write the grade
     try {
       double final_grade = grade(students[i]);
       streamsize prec = cout.precision();
       cout << setprecision(3) << final_grade
        << setprecision(prec);
     } catch (domain_error e) {
       cout << e.what();
     }

     cout << endl;
       }

     return 0;
       }
```

The code for `main1.cc`, `main2.cc` and `main3.cc` all compiles using a single `makefile` and `make` statement. Here are the contents of `makefile`. I do not believe `main2.cc` uses any of the `header` files mentioned in this `makefile` but I did not make any changes to the `makefile`. I have not pasted the contents of any of these `header` files here. If they are relevant to `main2.cc` I can provide them on request or they are all available at the GitHub site above.

```
CXX = g++
CC = g++

all:        main1 main2 main3

Student_info.o: Student_info.cc Student_info.h

grade.o:    grade.cc grade.h median.h Student_info.h

main3.o:    main3.cc grade.h median.h Student_info.h

median.o:   median.cc median.h

main3:      main3.o grade.o median.o Student_info.o

test:       all
    ./main1 <../data/single_grade
    ./main2 <../data/single_grade
    ./main2 <../data/grades
    ./main3 <../data/grades

clobber:
    rm -f *.o *.exe core main1 main2 main3
```

I have created a `subfolder` called `data` and put two data files in it: `grades` and `single_grade`. Here are the contents of `grades`:

```
Moo 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
Moore 75 85 77 59 0 85 75 89
Norman 57 78 73 66 78 70 88 89
Olson 89 86 70 90 55 73 80 84
Peerson 47 70 82 73 50 87 73 71

Russel 72 87 88 54 55 82 69 87
Thomas 90 96 99 99 100 81 97 97
Vaughn 81 97 99 67 40 90 70 96
Westerly 43 98 96 79 100 82 97 96


Baker 67 72 73 40 0 78 55 70
Davis 77 70 82 65 70 77 83 81
Edwards 77 72 73 80 90 93 75 90
Franklin 47 70 82 73 50 87 73 71

Jones 77 82 83 50 10 88 65 80
Harris 97 90 92 95 100 87 93 91
Smith 87 92 93 60 0 98 75 90
Carpenter 47 90 92 73 100 87 93 91

Fail1 45 55 65 80 90 70 65 60
Fail2 55 55 65 50 55 60 65 60
```

Here are the contents of `single_grade`:

```
harriet 85 95 88 87 93 45 76 99
```

The only place I find these two data files mentioned in any of the above code is in the `makefile` which confuses me, but I guess the `makefile` associates `main2.cc` and the two data files.

Here are the contents of `"minmax.h"`:

```
/**
 * This file has no copyright assigned and is placed in the Public Domain.
 * This file is part of the mingw-w64 runtime package.
 * No warranty is given; refer to the file DISCLAIMER.PD within this package.
 */
#ifndef _INC_MINMAX
#define _INC_MINMAX

#ifndef __cplusplus
#ifndef NOMINMAX
#ifndef max
#define max(a,b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#endif

#ifndef min
#define min(a,b) (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#endif
#endif
#endif

#endif
```

Here is what is returned by `c++ -v` on my `Windows 10` laptop:

```
c:\Users\mark_\myCppprograms>c++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/rtools/MINGW_64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-4.9.3/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw64 --with-sysroot=/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/x86_64-493-posix-seh-rt_v3-s/mingw64 --with-gxx-include-dir=/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++ --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --enable-libatomic --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --disable-isl-version-check --disable-cloog-version-check --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-bootstrap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=core2 --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-isl=/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-cloog=/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --enable-cloog-backend=isl --with-pkgversion='x86_64-posix-seh, Built by MinGW-W64 project' --with-bugurl=http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -I/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/x86_64-493-posix-seh-rt_v3-s/mingw64/opt/include -I/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -I/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/x86_64-493-posix-seh-rt_v3-s/mingw64/opt/include -I/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CPPFLAGS= LDFLAGS='-pipe -L/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/x86_64-493-posix-seh-rt_v3-s/mingw64/opt/lib -L/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/lib -L/home/Jeroen/mingw-gcc-4.9.3/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/lib '
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.3 (x86_64-posix-seh, Built by MinGW-W64 project)

c:\Users\mark_\myCppprograms>
```

I am aware that other people have uploaded solutions to Accelerated C++ exercises. I have looked at several. But I have not been able to get any of them to run with `main2.cc` or `main3.cc` and return the expected results.

Comment: "I am working through Accelerated C++ by Andrew Koenig and Barbara Moo (2000)" - I would *strongly* advice against learning C++ from a 20 year old book. The language has evolved greatly and with the introduction of C++11 it is a much different language than it was before - and C++14, 17 & 20 have only made the gap between modern C++ and C++ of two decades ago wider. Don't learn from obsolete material.

Comment: If you are teaching yourself C++, then one of the things you must eventually learn is how to use your debugger. Your debugger allows you to run your program, one line at a time, while inspecting the values of all variables, and monitor them as they change, and observe your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions, and it sounds like this is an excellent opportunity for you learn how to do this, right?

Comment: Koenig and Moo's book was truly remarkable back when. I used to recommended it to every new C++ developer. Unfortunately, today it is inadequate. I wish there was an updated version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you actually run it, but in my case it works perfectly fine. If you take a closer look at `main` in `main2.cc`, you'll notice that there's a blocking `read` call, which causes the program to wait for user input. Take a look at `test` target from makefile:

```
test:           all
        ./main1 <../data/single_grade
        ./main2 <../data/single_grade
        ./main2 <../data/grades
        ./main3 <../data/grades
```

`<` means that we'll be redirecting what's in `single_grade` to the process being run. It's implicitly assumed that in folder above to the executable binary will be a `data` directory with `single_grade` data file. So, when you run `$ make test`, you'll notice that everything works as expected (assuming the directory structure is unchanged). If you simply run `$ ./main2`, nothing is gonna happen as the program awaits for input. Or, assuming your data file is next to `main2` binary, you could run `$ main2 < single_grade`. Or, alternatively, you could omit the files at all:

```
$ ./main2
$ Moo 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
$ Moore 75 85 77 59 0 85 75 89
$ EOF (in bash shell it's CTRL + D, on windows cmd: CTRL + Z)
```

Which yields:

```
Moo   100
Moore 79.4
```